# Find a 2x2 Matrix A where Eλ is the eigenspace associated with the eigenvalue λ

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

[Not very sure where to start with this question. Can someone point me in the right direction?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bpu0X.png)

Answer (score 0):

Start with 
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{cc} a&b \\ c&d\end{array}\right)
$$
and search for the unknowns $a,b,c,d$ so that
\begin{align}
A\left(\begin{array}{c} -2 \\ 5\end{array}\right)&=5\left(\begin{array}{c} -2 \\ 5\end{array}\right)\tag{1} \\
A\left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ -3\end{array}\right)&=1\left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ -3\end{array}\right)\, .\tag{2}
\end{align}
You will get $4$ equations for your $4$ unknowns, and this system has a unique solution.  As a bonus you can verify that $\hbox{Tr}(A)=a+d=5+1=6$ and that $\hbox{det}(A)=5\times 1=5$.  As a hint, the entries of $A$ are all integers.

Comment: How do I create the 4 equations when trying to solve for a, b, c and d?

Comment: @MtManDan Use the form of $A$ and explicit matrix multiplication in (1) and (2).

Comment: which would give me equations: -10a +c, -10b+d, 25a-3c, and 25b-3d correct?

Comment: @MtManDan $-2a+5b=-10$ etc.